# ¿Cómo unir dos funciones en una sola?

Tags: javascript

Mi duda es con respecto a como unir 2 funciones (Tamaño máximo de un archivo y tipo de archivo) para formar una sola función y llamarla desde un input.

```
function checkFileSize() {
            var CV = document.getElementById("CV");
            var files = CV.files;

            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (files[0].size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) { // Validar la restricción
                    CV.setCustomValidity("El archivo seleccionado no debe ser mayor a 2MB");
                    return;
                }
            }
            CV.setCustomValidity("");
        }

function fileValidation() {
            var fileInput = document.getElementById("CV");
            var filePath = fileInput.value;
            var allowedExtensions = /(.pdf|.odt|.doc|.docx)$/i;

            if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
                alert('Solo se aceptan archivos en formato Pdf(.pdf), Word(.doc/.docx), OpenDocument(.odt)');
                fileInput.value = '';
                return false;
            }
```

Intente hacer esto:

```
function dosfunciones() {
          checkFileSize();
          fileValidation();
        }
```

Para después llamarlo en en input por el `onchange="checkFileSize(); fileValidation();` pero no me lee mas que una de las funciones.

Comment: puedes agregar  el input a ver como lo estas realizando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo que haría sería organizar las dos funciones para que se ejecuten en una sola, lo que veo es que simplemente se valida el peso y la extensión de un archivo, entonces lo resolvería de la siguiente manera:

```js
function validateFile(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("CV").files[0];

    if (fileInput != undefined) {
        var size = fileInput.size;
        var ext = '.' + fileInput.name.split('.')[1]

        var allowedExtensions = /(.pdf|.odt|.doc|.docx)$/i;

        if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
            alert('El archivo seleccionado no debe ser mayor a 2MB');
            document.getElementById("CV").value = "";
            return false;
        }else if(!allowedExtensions.exec(ext)){
            alert('Solo se aceptan archivos en formato Pdf(.pdf), Word(.doc/.docx), OpenDocument(.odt)');
            document.getElementById("CV").value = "";
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="" id="CV" onchange="validateFile();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma, agregando ambas funciones al llamado de `onclick`:

```
 <input type="button" value="click" onclick="checkFileSize(); fileValidation();"/>
```

Si solo "lee" una de las funciones, probablemente tienes un error en la función que no permite su ejecución.